# container engine kubernetes and ssl

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

How do I have a web app on HTTPS on google cloud container engine using HTTPS load balancing? I created SslCertificate resource. And, I created a kubernetes service that has port 443 externally open:

```
{
    "kind":"Service",
    "apiVersion":"v1",
    "metadata":{
        "name":"app",
        "labels":{
            "app":"app"
        }
    },
    "spec":{
        "ports": [
            {
                "port":443,
                "name":"app-server"
            }
        ],
        "selector":{
            "app":"app"
        },
        "type": "LoadBalancer"
    }
}
```

, but that's not enough, or right?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a service externalized on Google's cloud with the "LoadBalancer" directive, it creates an [L3 load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/). You can also use the new ingress directive to create an [L7 (e.g. HTTP) balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/), but that doesn't yet support SSL.

To enable SSL, you should follow the [HTTP Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) instructions but create an HTTPS service (with an SSL certificate) when configuring the cloud load balancer.

Comment: To expand on the SSL/HTTP Load balancing question.  Would you first create the HTTP Load Balancer with no backend services?  Then do something like 'kubectl expose rc frontend --port=443 --target-port=8000 --load-balancer-ip=X.X.X.X' with the static IP from the newly HTTP Load Balancer?  Also, what is the best way to troubleshoot the load balancer to Container Engine Service?

Comment: I wrote out some (vague) instructions on how to create an HTTPS load balancer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446512/is-it-possible-to-use-1-kubernetes-ingress-object-to-route-traffic-to-k8s-servic/35447985#35447985 (which was a slightly different question, but the solution is basically the same).